# Как в angular2 сделать страницу 404 с кодом 404, а не 200 как это происходит?

Tags: .htaccess, angular2

Можно ли прописать в роутах, или в самом компоненте для 404 страницы заголовок с нужным кодом (404) ? На текущий момент страница 404 возвращает статус код 200.

Comment: А это не на уровне сервера делается?

Comment: @Byulent ну вообще да, это делается на сервере. Но проблема в том, что обработка роутов происходит на клиенте.